# How to make dependencyManagement in Maven transitive

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, dependency-management

In maven, **dependencyManagement** can be used to resolve dependency conflict problems.

Now I'm developping a common lib project which will be used by many other projects. I want to use **dependencyManagement** to resolve all dependency conflicts so that other projects don't need to handle it.

However, when I add the common lib as **dependency** of other projects, I find that the **dependencyManagement** not works. In other words, I meet the same dependency conflict problems which already been resolved in **dependencyManagement** of the common lib.

I know copy-paste of **dependencyManagement** to everywhere is a way to make it, but it's very ugly and hard to maintain.

Is there any other way to achieve the goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your "common lib" can declare the desired versions as `<dependency>` (not just in dependencyManagement) and can also use exclusions to exclude the undesired ones. This works also transitively.

It would be great to have transitivity also for dependencyManagement, but it might make the very complex dependency resolution process of Maven even more complex.

Comment: Since maven do not support global exclude, the only way is to exclude all conflicts one by one?

Comment: What do you mean by `global exclude`?

Comment: You can only exclude at the dependencies, not globally. So the exclusion of a given library may take several entries. The question is whether exclusions are necessary. Let me give an example: If you want your library to use log4j 1.2.17, putting log4j 1.2.17 as dependency is enough. If you want dependencyConvergence in the enforcer plugin, you need additional excludes.